# Test of time and complexity recursive and iteration factorial program in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

I tried check memory complexity for recursive and iteration program computing factorial.

I assume that solution is `O(N)`, not interesting how implemented is multiplication.

But when I compared time of solution for two cases recursive and iteration I had different results.

```
Time of execution of factorial (loop) : 521.7680931091309 
Time of execution  (recursive) : 1214.137077331543
```

```py
import time

# O(n) complexity 
def factorial(n):
   result = 1
   for i in range(1, n+1):
       result *= i
   return result

# O(n) complexity 

def factorial_rec(n):
   if n <= 1:
       return 1
   else:
       return n * factorial_rec(n-1)


MAX_N = 100
COUNT = 100000

t1 = time.time()
for _ in range(0, COUNT):
   factorial(MAX_N)
t2 = time.time()
print(f"Time of execution of factorial (loop) : {(t2-t1)*1000} ")

t1 = time.time()
for _ in range(0, COUNT):
   factorial_rec(MAX_N)
t2 = time.time()
print(f"Time of execution  (recursive) : {(t2-t1)*1000} ")
```

Where is the differences between implementation of recursive in Python and iteration process?

Comment: you use `factorial` both times instead of using `factorial_rec` for one of them

Comment: But this question still make sens. @JohnColeman please try execution.

Comment: In your original question, the run-times seemed to be the same (which is what you seemed to be asking about, since it *would* be surprising if they were). As modified, you seem to be asking why they are different despite both being `O(n)`. I agree that this question makes sense, though it is based on a misunderstanding of big-O notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recursive solution runs slower than the nonrecursive solution. This is to be expected. The recursive solution involves a nontrivial amount of function-call overhead.

It is not true that two `O(n)` algorithms will have the same run-time. They have the same *complexity*, but the definition of `O(n)` involves an unspecified constant of proportionality (which in the linear case is simply the slope of the line). Not all lines have the same slope. The slope for the recursive case is just bigger than the slope for the nonrecursive case. Think of it this way. If `n = 10`, the recursive function requires 10 function calls. If `n = 20`, it requires 20 function calls, etc. Note how that goes up linearly and is thus part of the slope. There is nothing which corresponds to this cost in the nonrecursive case. Other than the function call overhead, the computation is mostly just multiplication (which is the same in both cases) -- so the recursive function is almost obviously less efficient. It incurs a cost that the other function does not.